# WiX - .NET 4.0 prerequisite increasing file size?

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

Below is the following code I am using for a WiX bootstrapper to install a program:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle Name='My Application Version 3.5'  Version='3.5.0' Manufacturer='Company'       UpgradeCode='{49DF3192-2631-4636-9279-E4F913077C57}'>
            <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

              <Chain>
                <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full"/>
                <MsiPackage SourceFile="MyApplicationToInstall.msi" Compressed="no"/>
              </Chain>
  </Bundle>

        <Fragment>
            <!--check for .NET 4.0-->
            <util:RegistrySearch
                Root="HKLM"
                Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                Value="Version" Variable="Netfx40FullVersion"/>

            <util:RegistrySearch
                Root="HKLM"
                Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                Value="Version"
                Variable="Netfx40x64FullVersion"
                Win64="yes"/>

            <PackageGroup Id="Netfx4Full">
                <ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full"
                     DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0"
                     DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/A/95A9616B-7A37-4AF6-BC36-D6EA96C8DAAE/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
                     Compressed="no"
                     Cache="no"
                     PerMachine="yes"
                     Permanent="yes"
                     Vital="yes"
                     Protocol="netfx4"
                     SourceFile=".\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
                     InstallCommand="/passive /norestart"
                     DetectCondition="Netfx40FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx40x64FullVersion)" />
            </PackageGroup>
        </Fragment>
    </Wix>
```

For some reason, The prerequisite of .NET 4 has caused a 3 MB application to increase to the file size of 99 MB. When I removed the prerequisite, It went down to the size it was supposed to be (3 MB). After some research, I changed cache from "yes" to "no", reducing it from 99 MB to 50 MB.

I'm relatively new to WiX, so what am I missing? Have I written the prerequisite incorrectly?

EDIT: The original program was installed using VS2010's installer template (which is now discontinued) which, when ran, installed this program with the same prerequisite as the WiX alternative I have written, however the result of that installation installed the 3 MB program and  .NET as seperate entities.

Comment: If your package installs the .NET Framework if it's not installed, I don't see anything wrong with an increased package size. Where else would the framework be installed from?

Comment: but why would that affect the size of the installed program? .NET is a separate entity that is simply required for said program to run. My installed program shouldn't be showing up as a 50 MB program in the control panel, when in reality the program itself is only 3 MB.

Comment: That depends on the way you are looking at it. Your installer installed 99MB. Part of it maybe was the .NET Framework, but still, this installer installed it, so it is indeed the size of your installation. If the user removed it, that's the space that would be freed, right? You can run a test on what happend when someone else needs .NET4, and installs it, too.

Comment: The reason this is baffling me though (and I should probably have added this in the question but forgot to) is that the original application was installed via VS2010's installer template, and the original size of the program that installed was 3 MB, so that suggests to me that I've set up something incorrectly with the WiX installer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RemotePayload instead of specifying SourceFile. The sample code I used to install .NET 3.5:

```
<PackageGroup Id="DotNetFx35">
  <ExePackage 
    InstallCommand="/lang:enu /passive /qb /norestart" 
    PerMachine="yes" 
    DetectCondition="NETFX35" 
    InstallCondition="NOT NETFX35" 
    Id="DotNetFx35" 
    Vital="yes" 
    Permanent="yes" 
    Protocol="none" 
    DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=118076" 
    Compressed="no" 
    Name="dotnetfx35setup.exe">
    <RemotePayload 
      Size="2959376" 
      Version="3.5.30792.01" 
      ProductName="Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5" 
      Description="Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Setup"            Hash="ec9f0c31b9949ca1cf14e9a43bca065fa5bc0e71" /> 
  </ExePackage>
  </PackageGroup>
```

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your example for .NET 4, however I'm not sure where I could find the hash code for the installer (that's the hash code I'm assuming I'll need), is there anywhere I could find it? because I've had no luck finding it so far, thanks.

Comment: It is possible to find online hash calculators. I use FreeWare utility HashTool http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/hash.html. When you generate  hash, check that you chose SHA-1 hash.

Comment: When I remove SourceFile, it won't compile. It states that it is a required attribute. What can I do to circumvent this?